# How to dispaly a holding screen whilst ActiveJob retrieves lots of data from an external API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activejob

I have an application that makes API requests to salesforce using [restforce](https://github.com/ejholmes/restforce).

Specifically the application finds a contact object, returns IDs for all related objects and then pulls the full record for every related object based on their ID.

This takes a long time for two reasons:

1. There are a lot of request to an external API, usually takes a few fractions of a second for each to reply and for some there can be +500 individual requests.
2. There is often a large amount of data being pulled back via each request.

All requests currently fall within the salesforce rest [API limits](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/resources_limits.htm) but I'm getting timeout errors from my development server as it can take 5+ minutes for some of these requests to process.

**Rails 4.2 - How best to handle this?**

My question is how do I best get rails to handle this?

I can fire the API requests either from the controller (which definitely violates the skinny controllers) or from the view (via helper methods, which seems like a dodgy hack).

Ideally I'd like to get it running in a background job, but i'm unsure if I can just include all the authentication and other methods in a job in the same way I can include helper methods?

Even if I could get it to work in a background job, I'm unsure what best practice might be for the user experience. Ideally I'd like to route them to a page telling them to "hang tight, go get a coffee" with a progress bar, and then auto route them to the final page once the request is complete...

But I'm unsure how to generate a temporary display until a job has been completed?

Could anyone recommend any gems or strategies that might help me digest this problem?

Comment: Might be a good idea to delegate the time-consuming task to a background process. Check out  http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html & http://www.sitepoint.com/comparing-ruby-background-processing-libraries-delayed-job/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely use a background job for this.

Give a database object to the job, which it will update to signal that is has finished, and maybe from time to time to indicate progress.

On the user side, simply tell them that the background job is working, with eventually a progress indicator, and display the result once the database object giving to the job tells you it's ready.

Comment: Thanks @Geoffroy - I've come to the same conclusion. Although i am struggling slightly to implement. I think my google searches are getting confused between Background Jobs and ActiveJob (new in Rails 4.2?). I've been using the following guides: [Active Job Basics](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) & [5 Tips for Deploying Background Jobs in Ruby on Rails](https://blog.engineyard.com/2009/5-tips-for-deploying-background-jobs). If there are any other great guides please do post them up for myself and others just wading into this territory!

Comment: ActiveJob is an API to create (possibly) background jobs, which uses different adapters depending on the backend you need. You generally start a worker to execute jobs.